# File sharing with webrtc legality?

Tags: webrtc, sharing

If I only open a data channel directly between clients using webrtc in my webpage, then allow clients to share information on what files they have available and further share files through the data channel, can I be prosecuted in any way for allowing the sharing of illegal content?
While the illegally shared files will show directly on my webpage, the source of this will not be from the server hosting the js files, but rather from other clients once the data channel is opened between them

Comment: We are not lawyers.

Comment: yeh but lawyers wont likely understand what webrtc is lol. I already have a chat site which would be great for this and mimics a desktop. It would be like having windows that are each a facebook feed and you can post anything you like on. http://chatdimension.com/

Comment: You need a tech lawyer.  They exist, and they should know what WebRTC is.

Comment: If you upset rich people they will prosecute you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [law.stackexchange.com](http://law.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can be accused of promoting a channel to facilitate the transfer of illegal content...
Also, as you should know, WebRTC is not always peer to peer: TURN servers are used to relay traffic if direct (peer to peer) connection fails. So technically, if you own a TURN server, illegal content would be part of the traffic of your server.